# Tax printed twice in sales order emails

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

We have Tax defined as 7% GST in Tax configuration and is printed fine everywhere except the emails sent for order confirmation where there is a separate row as Tax and a mention of the 7% so with both there it is confusing for the users. Check the screenshot attached. 
Is it possible to remove one of that? How to remove it? I checked the layout file for email and it had only Tax block defined as single block so if I take it out, then whole Tax will be gone from there.
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your code if you have done any custom code. Email template as well

Comment: Tax description comes from `module-tax/view/frontend/templates/order/tax.phtml` you can customize here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

login in Magento admin section and navigate to

store -> configration -> sales -> Tax

Click on **shopping cart display settings** and make sure you have No for **Display Full Tax Summary**. If it is yes make it No.

After change configuration Clear cache.

Please find attachment
[image]

Comment: I realised this was changed somehow and was giving the problem, Now after changing this the extra tax row is gone. Thanks a lot